# Will this statement always evaluate to nil in Swift?

Tags: swift, user-interface, button

```
open var buttonInit: ((_ index: Int) -> UIButton?)?
...
if let button: UIButton = self.buttonInit?(i) {
    finButton = button
}else {
        let button = UIButton(type: .custom)
        button.setTitleColor(button.tintColor, for: [])
        button.layer.borderColor = button.tintColor.cgColor
        button.layer.borderWidth = 1
        button.layer.cornerRadius = buttonHeight/2
        finButton = button
}
```

I don't find any function description about **buttonInit** in [AZDialogViewController](https://github.com/Minitour/AZDialogViewController/blob/master/Sources/AZDialogViewController.swift). Does it mean **button: UIButton = self.buttonInit?(i)** will always be nil and **finButton = button** will not be executed?

Comment: how and when are you doing this code? As far as I can understand, you are using a `buttonInit` in a different way than what it is made for.

Answer (score 1):

The latter part of the code you quoted is in the `setUpButton` method:

```
fileprivate func setupButton(index i:Int) -> UIButton{
    if buttonHeight == 0 {buttonHeight = CGFloat(Int(deviceHeight * 0.07))}

    let finButton: UIButton

    if let button: UIButton = self.buttonInit?(i) {
        finButton = button
    }else {
        let button = UIButton(type: .custom)
        button.setTitleColor(button.tintColor, for: [])
        button.layer.borderColor = button.tintColor.cgColor
        button.layer.borderWidth = 1
        button.layer.cornerRadius = buttonHeight/2
        finButton = button
    }
```

This method is called here:

```
open func addAction(_ action: AZDialogAction){
    actions.append(action)

    if buttonsStackView != nil{
        let button = setupButton(index: actions.count-1)
        self.buttonsStackView.addArrangedSubview(button)
        //button.frame = buttonsStackView.bounds
        button.center = CGPoint(x: buttonsStackView.bounds.midX,y: buttonsStackView.bounds.maxY)
        animateStackView()
    }
}
```

From this we can see that `buttonInit` seems to be used to let the user of the library specify what kind of button they want as the action buttons. Another piece of evidence is that `buttonInit` is declared `open`, so it is likely that it is the client code who should set this, not the `AZDialogViewController`.

Plus, the [`README`](https://github.com/Minitour/AZDialogViewController#use-custom-uibutton-sub-class) file showed this usage:

> **Use custom UIButton sub-class:**
>
> ```
> dialog.buttonInit = { index in
>     //set a custom button only for the first index
>     return index == 0 ? HighlightableButton() : nil
> }
> ```

So to answer your question, the `if` branch will be executed if *you* set `buttonInit`.

Answer (score 0):

@Huwell,
the documentation in the repository states to initialize the button in the following manner:

```
dialog.buttonInit = { index in
    //set a custom button only for the first index
    return index == 0 ? HighlightableButton() : nil
}
```

The button should be part of your DialogViewController.